# Search for key in json object

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to make an area class that sums up all instances of the key 'area' in a json string.

For example `e = Area('[1, 2, 3, {"area": 123, "weight": 1000}]')` should return `e=123` and this `Area('["Hello", "World", {"area": 999}, {"area": 1}]')` should return 1000.

At the moment I'm just getting 0 returned everytime and I think this may be because I'm initializing `sum` too early or because my indexing into the string may be off.

```
import json
class Area:

    def __init__(self, txt):
        self.txt=txt

    def __str__(self):
        sum=0
            for a in self.txt:
                if a == 'area':
                    sum+=int(self.txt[a]})
        return str(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

using `json.loads` is fine but you  need to make sure you have a dict which you  can do with [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance), you can use the builtin [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function to do the summing for you.

```
import json
class Area:
    def __init__(self, txt):
        self.txt = txt
    def __str__(self):
        return str(sum(d.get("area", 0) for d in json.loads(self.txt) 
                  if isinstance(d, dict)))
```

Output:

```
In [8]: e = Area('[1, 2, 3, {"area": 123, "weight": 1000}]')

In [9]: print e
123
In [10]: e = Area('["Hello", "World", {"area": 999}, {"area": 1}]') 

In [11]: print e
1000
```

In your own code  you are iterating over the characters in the string  as you never call `loads` so `if a == 'area':` would never be True as you are comparing "area" to each individual char, as is your code would also  error as `self.txt[a]}` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

Then you should test each element of the list to see if it contains an item `area`, you should bear in mind that not all items in the list will support the `in` operator, so wrap it in an exception block.

Lastly it does seem odd that you are doing all this in the `__str__` method. It might be better to have a method that returns

```
import json

class Area:
def __init__(self, txt):
    self.txt = json.loads(txt)

def __str__(self):
    sum = 0
    for a in self.txt:
        try:
            if 'area' in a:
                sum += int(a['area'])
        except TypeError:
            pass
    return str(sum)


print Area('[1, 2, 3, {"area": 123, "weight": 1000}]')
print Area('["Hello", "World", {"area": 999}, {"area": 1}]')
```